# Underline cvlist heading whole line

Tags: cv, currvita

Is there a way to underline the whole line in the cvlist heading? (Not only the heading letters at the beginning, the line should last over the whole as in the attachd picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mvS1.png))

My code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(380,600){\includegraphics[width=50mm] 
{Bewerbungsfoto.jpg}}}
%\sffamily
\begin{cv}{\LARGE{Lebenslauf}}  
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{cvlist}{Persöhnliche Daten}  
\item [Name] Peter Parker
\item [Geburtsdatum] 11.11.11111
\item [Anschrift] street\\ xxxxx City
\item [Familienstand] ledig
\item [Telefon] +49 (0) 111 11 11 11 11
\item [Email] test@yahoo.com
\end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image: Whole heading line underlined]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the sections underlined. That can be done with the command `\sectionrule` from the `sectsty` package, that draws one line above and one below the title. In the below code I got some help from Google with the German name of your title:-). I also moved the picture a bit to get it better aligned with the right margin.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[]{currvita}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-0.5ex}{0.5pt}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(350,580){\includegraphics[width=45mm] {example-image}}}
%\sffamily
\begin{cv}{\LARGE{Lebenslauf}}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{cvlist}{Persönliche Daten}  
\item [Name] Peter Parker
\item [Geburtsdatum] 11.11.11111
\item [Anschrift] street\\ xxxxx City
\item [Familienstand] ledig
\item [Telefon] +49 (0) 111 11 11 11 11
\item [Email] test@yahoo.com
\end{cvlist}
\section*{\MakeUppercase{Berufserfahrung}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]